# minimal Fortran file that compiles with any compiler

Tags: cmake, fortran

CMake developers [recommend adding a dummy Fortran file](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-July/038172.html) to tell CMake that static libraries need to be linked with Fortran libraries (for example when linking C program with LAPACK).

My first thought was to use empty `dummy.f`. But [ifort 9.0 won't compile it](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/268961).

What is the minimal portable dummy Fortran file?

Is old Intel compiler the only one that has problem with empty file?

Answer (score 3):

Same error with GFortran and Absoft Fortran. Actually, you need a "program" block to build an executable.
This dummy.f would work:

```
      program dummy
      end
```

According to standard, "A Fortran program must contain one main program and may contain any number of the other kinds of program units". (see "Fortran 95 handbook" by Adams et al., section 2.1.1 p.19)

Or in [standard Fortran 95](http://j3-fortran.org/doc/standing/archive/007/97-007r2/pdf/97-007r2.pdf) same section 2.2.1, p.12:

```
A program consists of exactly one main program unit and any number
(including zero) of other kinds of program units. The set of program
units may include any combination of the different kinds of program
units in any order as long as there is only one main program unit.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need *main program unit*, only a dummy file (translation unit) that will be compiled and linked with real program in different language. GFortran accepts empty file: `touch dummy.F; gfortran -c dummy.F`

Comment: In that case replace program with subroutine.

Comment: @marcin. Actually, the standard define program units (function, subroutine, program). It has no idea what a "program file" is, it just know of program units. Thus, an empty file defines nothing at all. However, it's not absolutely clear whether or not you can still build an empty object file from an empty source file - I'm not sure it has anything to do with Fortran. But you may still rely on the above code, replacing *program* with *subroutine* as pointed out by cup.

Comment: I'm more concerned about portability (i.e. what works with popular compilers) rather than about standard compliance. I think that empty subroutine, as proposed by @cup, will work. OTOH I was also thinking that empty file would work and it turned out that it doesn't work with at least one old compiler.

Comment: *Empty routine* is a valid Fortran *program unit*, not the empty file, period. No wonder you'll have portability issues sooner or later if you don't follow the standard (btw, how many popular compilers have you really tried ? how do you judge popularity of a compiler ?) - oh, and you will soon discover that you need to use even a subset of Fortran if you want portability: [F2003](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2003+status) and [F2008](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2008+status) are not fully supported yet.